# Tomcat 7 - Error page for error 500 not handled correctly

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I handled errors in my web.xml file but sometimes I get an error 500 with full stacktrace instead of what I expect, in example when connection to database is timed out and a JDBCException is thrown.

This is my web.xml :

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/app/error</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/app/error</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/index.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/app/403</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/app/404</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/app/405</location>
</error-page>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Because my answer do not explain reason beyond theory, I post it as comment.

Spring handle it somehow in it's internal and using web.xml might be not the case. Better use documented way of error handling Spring MVC: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc